# Possible to make suction cups work again after being unused for a few years?

Tags: shower, mounting

In the shower of my old apartment, I had a shower caddy with suction cups mounted in my shower. I then moved to a new place, and the shower caddy was never remounted in the new shower.

After being laid to rest in a box for almost two years, is there a way to get the suction cups to work again? Is there a coating of dust and fats that are preventing the cups from mounting on the wall, or have the suction function depreciated by some other means?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clean them thoroughly and they may work no problem.

However it's possible that the rubber hardened and cracked which means that you won't be able to get a grip with it anymore.

Comment: I cleaned them with soap and water, but strangely they won't "suck" anymore. Thankfully the caddy wasn't that expensive so I'll get a new one (or some new suction cups).